# Why is my laravel-livewire ->layout not working?

Tags: php, html, laravel-livewire

i'm trying to apply a style to my page using a Livewire model but it does not work and i can't find why.
Here is the code of my model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Home extends Component
{
  public function render()
  {
    return view('livewire.home')
        ->layout('layouts.tesswimlayout');
  }
}
```

Layout File

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
<meta name="description" content="Welkom bij TS">
<title>TS: {{ $title ?? '' }}</title>
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
@livewireStyles
</head>

<body class="font-sans antialiased">
<div class="flex flex-col space-y-4 min-h-screen text-gray-800 
bg-gray-100">
<header class="shadow bg-white/70 sticky inset-0 backdrop-blur-sm 
z-10">
    {{--  Navigation  --}}
    <nav class="container mx-auto p-4 flex justify-between items- 
center">
        <a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="underline">Home</a>
    </nav>
</header>
<main class="container mx-auto p-4 flex-1 px-4">

    {{-- Main content --}}
    {{ $slot }}
</main>
<x-layout.footer.footer/>
</div>
@stack('script')
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sure it's a simple mistake but i'm totally lost atm so any help is apreciated.

Comment: Show your layout blade file also

Comment: I just added my layout file

Comment: Not sure exactly but check this https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#applying-the-layout-component.. You may need `<x-...` in livewire page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple after all, I forgot to add @LivewireScripts to my layout. Thanks to those who tried to help.